# Converting an array into string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to join output of a hash into a string.

The hash looks like this:

```
 nas.location.walledgardens.to_s

  => "[#<Walledgarden id: 1, location_id: 12, url: \"polka.com\", created_at: \"2012-05-14 17:02:47\", updated_at: \"2012-05-14 17:02:47\">, #<Walledgarden id: 2, location_id: 12, url: \"test.com\", created_at: \"2012-05-14 17:02:47\", updated_at: \"2012-05-14 17:02:47\">, #<Walledgarden id: 3, location_id: 12, url: \"help.com\", created_at: \"2012-05-14 17:02:47\", updated_at: \"2012-05-14 17:02:47\">, #<Walledgarden id: 4, location_id: 12, url: \"yell.com\", created_at: \"2012-05-14 17:02:47\", updated_at: \"2012-05-14 17:02:47\">, #<Walledgarden id: 5, location_id: 12, url: \"sausage.com\", created_at: \"2012-05-14 17:02:47\", updated_at: \"2012-05-14 17:02:47\">]"
```

I need to join the url values into the following format:

```
polka.com,test.com,help.com
```

What the best way to do this? I can easily look through it but the output has line breaks and I need these removed plus the commas.

Comment: require 'csv'; `nas.location.walledgardens.map(&:url).to_csv` ?

Comment: @SeamusAbshere IMO, loading a CSV library is overkill for this simple example. But perhaps the OP is looking to apply this in a situation where the string needs to be parsed again later — in which case that's definitely a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
nas.location.walledgardens.collect { |w| w.url }.join(",")
```

The `.collect` method will collect all what that block returns and put it in an array, and then the join puts that array in a string, separated by whatever you give it (so a comma).

Comment: Actually Hauleth's map is better!

Comment: @MrDanA: Well `map` is just an alias for `collect` and `&:url` is just the `Symbol#to_proc` shortcut for your block, so in essence it's the same solution. :-)

Comment: @MichaelKohl I had no idea it was just a short cut like that, but it mainly just looks so much nicer. Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 6):

What you have is not a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html), but an [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) of Walledgarden objects (they look to be [ActiveRecord::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) subclasses).

Try this:

```
nas.location.walledgardens.collect(&:url).join ","
```

(Note: `#map` and `#collect` are equivalent, so which one you choose should be a consideration of readability!)

Comment: @phrogz! Yeah, you lot were too quick :) Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
nas.location.walledgardens.map(&:url).join ','
```